# Rotate and Scale rectangle as per user control

Tags: c#, graphics, drawrectangle

I have UserControl of Size 300*200.
and rectangle of size 300*200.

```
graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 300, 200);
```

When I rotate rectangle in userControl by 30 degree, I get rotated rectangle but it is outsized.

```
PointF center = new PointF(150,100);
graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, center.X, center.Y, 2, 2); // draw center point.

using (Matrix matrix = new Matrix())
{
      matrix.RotateAt(30, center);
      graphics.Transform = matrix;
      graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, 300, 200);
      graphics.ResetTransform();
}
```

I want to fit rectangle like actual result.[Check Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkvvy.png)

Can anyone have solution about this.

Thanks.

Comment: It's doing exactly what you ask it to. it rotates. If you'll do it with a piece of paper, you'll see that it's the same. what you want is rotate AND scale i assume.

Comment: @Noctis - Do you have any solution to this?

Comment: If you're using WPF, you could also simply use a `LayoutTransform` instead of a `RenderTransform`, and achieve the same, minus the math...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's more of a math question than programming one.

Calculate bouning box of any rectangle rotated by any angle in radians.

```
var newWidth= Math.Abs(height*Math.Sin(angle)) + Math.Abs(width*Math.Cos(angle))
var newHeight= Math.Abs(width*Math.Sin(angle)) + Math.Abs(height*Math.Cos(angle))
```

Calculate scale for x and y:

```
scaleX = width/newWidth;
scaleY = height/newHeight;
```

Apply it to your rectangle.

**EDIT**:
Applied to your example:

```
    PointF center = new PointF(150, 100);
    graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, center.X, center.Y, 2, 2); // draw center point.
    var height = 200;
    var width = 300;
    var angle = 30;
    var radians = angle * Math.PI / 180;
    var boundingWidth = Math.Abs(height * Math.Sin(radians)) + Math.Abs(width * Math.Cos(radians));
    var boundingHeight = Math.Abs(width * Math.Sin(radians)) + Math.Abs(height * Math.Cos(radians));
    var scaleX = (float)(width / boundingWidth);
    var scaleY = (float)(height / boundingHeight);
    using (Matrix matrix = new Matrix())
    {
        matrix.Scale(scaleX, scaleY, MatrixOrder.Append);
        matrix.Translate(((float)boundingWidth - width) / 2, ((float)boundingHeight - height) / 2);
        matrix.RotateAt(angle, center);
        graphics.Transform = matrix;
        graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 0, 0, width, height);
        graphics.ResetTransform();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But what if the size of rectangle changes means if it is 300*200.

Comment: @SagarKhade then you need to calculate it again. as far as i'm aware, `a^2 + b^2 = c^2` will still be true :)

Comment: But I mean to say that if usercontrol size is 300*200 fixed. and rectangle is also 300*200 and angle changes to 30. then?

Comment: You have asked for soluition for case when control is 400x400 and rectangle(square) is 400x400 it is difficult to answer without knowing what is desired outcome when dimensions change. For example, do you want rectangle to be stretched so corners are on control's edges or do you want to preserve it's aspect ratio? Please include other cases in the question.

Comment: Yes, rectangle to be stretched so corners are on control's edges and there are no other cases.

Comment: The solution you provided is not working. Can you please recheck it. Thanks