# How to correctly rotate image in C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am trying to add rotating of image in my WPF application. There is a code:

```
public static Bitmap RotateImage(Image inputImage, float angleDegrees)
{
    if (angleDegrees == 0f || angleDegrees == 360f)
        return (Bitmap)inputImage.Clone();

    int oldWidth = inputImage.Width;
    int oldHeight = inputImage.Height;
    int newWidth = inputImage.Width;
    int newHeight = inputImage.Height;

    Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    newBitmap.SetResolution(inputImage.HorizontalResolution, inputImage.VerticalResolution);

    using (Graphics graphicsObject = Graphics.FromImage(newBitmap))
    {
        graphicsObject.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        graphicsObject.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        graphicsObject.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        graphicsObject.TranslateTransform(newWidth / 2f, newHeight / 2f);
        graphicsObject.RotateTransform(angleDegrees);
        graphicsObject.TranslateTransform(-oldWidth / 2f, -oldHeight / 2f);

        graphicsObject.DrawImage(inputImage, 0, 0);
    }

    return newBitmap;
}
```

*Original code: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16027561/11601385*

Well, the image is rotated correctly, but there is a problem with image size.

[image: Before rotation]
[image: After rotation]

How can I change size of rotated image to make it correct?

Comment: If you are rotating +90 / -90 (or +270) degrees, then the newWidth = oldHeight and newHeight = oldWidth.

Comment: The original post you're quoting is a WinForms question, are you sure you wanna get inspiration from that for your WPF question?

Comment: The size you need is a matter of simple math.

Comment: Just set the LayoutTransform or RenderTransform of the Image element that shows the bitmap. Use a RotateTransform.

Comment: See if this works for you    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12655033/rotate-3d-cube-in-wpf/12655670#12655670

Comment: You're rotating a rectangular picture?  As you rotate, it shouldn't be too surprising when it doesn't fit. You need to work out what size rectangle will fit and scale it down. I think this is what is being done here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36540965/rotate-and-scale-rectangle-as-per-user-control